# Find an Element in xPath where the next Sibling has a specific Text

Tags: xpath

[image]

Hi I am trying to find a specific "only" keyword where the next Sibling has a specific Character. I am trying to use the below mentioned code but seems it is not returning any value. Would be great help if you can show me where I am wrong.

```
 //a[text()='only']/following-sibling::label[text()='Jet Airways']
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your query, [see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6emo4nLx/).  Likely your context is not what you think, for example executing the query in the console at the linked fiddle yields no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*These elements are not siblings* because they have different immediate parents.

You may go with [`following`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following) axis instead:

```
//a[. = 'only']/following::label[. = 'Jet Airways']
```

Or, you can work with the following `span` sibling instead:

```
//a[. = 'only']/following-sibling::span[label = 'Jet Airways']
```